# why i cannot open the apps after installation and find my apps on my phone

Tags: android

i would like to know any problem in this AndroidManifest.xml or another problem. Because i am just a beginner(i find some related post it is about AndroidManifest.xml problem and i still cannot find the problem, i tried many time install the apk file on my phone and still not work) i am not good at English,sorry about that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iShLu.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sung.beamexample_self"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="NFC Data Display">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

1. List item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this separate the intent filters like below intent filters**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```